# composing queries with mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I m trying to create dynamically the a query using mongoose base on some parameters

```
get<F extends Filterable>(filter: F, projections: { [fieldName: string]: 0 | 1 }, toEntity: (document: D) => Promise<T>) {
    const pagingFilter = { ...filter.page }
    const sortingFilter = { ...filter.sort }
    const dataFilter: any = omit(filter, ["page"])
    Object.keys(dataFilter).map((key) => {
        if (isUndefined(dataFilter[key])) {
            delete dataFilter[key]
        }
    })

    let query = this.model.find(dataFilter, projections)
    if (!isUndefined(pagingFilter.limit) && !isUndefined(pagingFilter.offset)) {
        query = query.limit(pagingFilter.limit).skip(pagingFilter.limit * pagingFilter.offset)
    }
    if (!isUndefined(sortingFilter.name) && !isUndefined(sortingFilter.order)) {
        query = query.sort({ [sortingFilter.name]: sortingFilter.order })
    }
    return Promise.all([
        this.model.count(dataFilter),
        query.exec()
    ])
        .then(([total, values]) => ({ total, values }))
}
```

If I pass the sort parameter, I should receive the parameters sorted, and the same for page parameters  but is not working for me

There is a way of compose queries in mongoose?